# How to write a JSDoc for adding a method to built-in objects?

Tags: javascript, jsdoc

I want to document a new method to an internal Array objects, so that I can use the method everytime I make an array. For example:

```
/**
* @<whatsInHere?> Array
* @returns {number}
*/
Array.prototype.avg = function () {
    let sum = 0;
    for (let _x = 0; _x < this.length; _x++) sum += this[_x];
    return sum / this.length;
}

const myArray = [3,4,5,6,34,5,2];
const average = myArray.avg();
```

What should I do to document avg?

Thank you;

UPDATE:
I've found about @external [here](https://jsdoc.app/tags-external.html) and modified mine like this:

```
/**
* @external Array
*/

/**
* @functions external:Array#avg
*
*/
Array.prototype.avg = function() {}
```

Did not work either. Or perhaps, I use it the wrong way?

Comment: Maybe this can help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27343152/jsdoc-how-to-document-prototype-methods

Comment: @Rajesh yeah.. tried that. Not working for built-in objects such as Array or String. I've also read about external, but it's either I don't know how to use it properly, or wrong keyword

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think I've found a workaround, but using typescript. Just put it under `<yourfile>.d.ts` and it would work in javascript as well.

**array.d.ts**

```
interface Array<T> {
    avg(): T
    myAwesomeMethod(fn: (param:T)=>T):T
    .
    .
}
```

**code.js**

```
Array.prototype.avg = function() { }
Array.prototype.myAwesomeMethod = function(fn) { }
```

Comment: and where is your comment?